# Laravel Discount Application Challenge

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose we have a discount code system, and we want to give a discount to the first 1000 people.

The challenge is that 100,000 requests per minute may come to our Laravel API. What's the best way to implement this service?

Note that my problem is concurrency and pressure on MySQL. I think 1000 times update and insert in 10 sec is too much.(and maybe raise many errors)

Comment: 1- prepare 1000 active discount code in database , 2- each user will search for the latest active discount code , 3- when an active discount code returned ,the user will get the discount  and the code will be expired

Comment: or maybe using some counter instead

Comment: Thanks, but we must generate one code. And my problem is concurrency and pressure on MySQL. I think 1000 times update and insert in 10 sec is too much.

Comment: it depends on your resources, I  think it's not that much

Comment: You could dispatch a queue job for each incoming request and process the update / insert inside theses jobs. Downside is: the users wont have a direct feedback and it will not be the first 1000 requests but the first 1000 processed jobs.